# Extending one type to re-use inside another type issue

Tags: typescript

I will try to explain what I am trying to do here. Recently, Like 2 months ago I started working with TypeScript. Since then I never want to go back to regular JS ever again. I used to hate it, but now I see the use of it and robust and clean code you can write without making any mistakes.

Now for my question, I have a type take for instance `PageProps` which looks like this:

```
type PagePros = {
  title: string;
  slug: string;
  description?: string;
}
```

The issue here is that I have the `title` on different types and am trying to create a cleaner and DRY-er approach without having to write the same over and over again.

So I did this:

```
type Title = {
  title: string;
}

type PagePros = Title & {
  slug: string;
  description?: string;
}
```

But the problem is it works, but VsCode and on hover of the `pageProps` it doesn't show the title but only shows the description type.

is this a valid and smart way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is how you would do it. It seems to be some bug in VSCode's plugin. Other way to do this is to use interface: `interface PageProps extends Title { slug: string; description?: string }`

Comment: @vighnesh153 Is this considered a clean and smart way of writing types instead of having the same values, over and over again?

Comment: @vighnesh153 What If I want to extend 2 types inside one type? Is this possible by any chance?

Comment: "clean" is debatable. I would say if you have just 1 prop that you want in multiple places, then it should be fine to just re-define it everywhere. If you have multiple props that you need to use at multiple places, you can also prefer composition: `type Props = { blog: Blog, slug: string, description: string }` where `Blog` is another type/interface

Comment: @vighnesh153 Thank you, Vignesh I also like the `interface` more looks cleaner.